# Send commands from a server to swift app

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am new to swift and was wondering how could I send commands from a server to my iOS application ? For example imagine a website where I can click a button and that button would then trigger a pop up to all users of my app. Is this possible and if so can someone lead me in the right direction?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can

1. **Silent Push Notification**: Send a Silent Push Notification and handle in your app. But you need user permissions to receive Notifications. Add `"content-available" : 1` to your notification content.
2. **Using Sockets**: There are many options to create connection b/w device and server. example: https://socket.io/

Comment: thank you for the information i will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do, you might want to look at apple push notifications and see how they work. From there I would suggest looking into sending notifications to the apple server (that would send the push notifications to the app). I hope this sends you in the right path good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just assume that you have an application that a number of users are using and you have a web application that can show all mobile users.

For the most of cases, whenever a user is using the application, you let the application send a request with your user's information to your server and your server records the user information in the database.

When your website wants to show all the users' information, it just fetches all the information from the database instead of sending sort of commands to all applications to get information in real-time.

Of course, there is a more complex way to send commands to all running applications to get the results. However, it requires both server-side and client-side (ios application) implement functions sending commands in real-time using Socket or MQTT etc. This is more complex and it requires iOS application running in front or background at the same time.

I assume that using HTTP to record every mobile user is more suitable for your case.